# Is [class*="span"] also contains .row-fluid [class*="span"] in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

In twitter bootstrap, I've recently faced these type of selection

```
[class*="span"],
.uneditable-input[class*="span"],
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I know that `[class*="span"]` means every element with a class name which has "span" within and I am familiar with rest of css.

But why do we have to also select `.row-fluid [class*="span"]` when `[class*="span"]` works on `.row [class*="span"]` ?

I removed this part (as I thought it would be redundant) but it seems browsers will not select elements with span class name if they are inside a `.row-fluid` elements. Can someone explain this behavior ?

Comment: Could be a specificity hack of sorts.

Comment: @BoltClock has it, though I wouldn't call it a hack. Check http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ if you need more details on specificity -- how diferent selectors receive different weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks David Taiaroa (see his comment below the question and his informative link), the reason that this occurs is selectors specification priority. I thought that later defined properties will override prior properties but it turns out that more specific selectors will override more general selectors regardless where are placed.

In this case `.row-fluid span1`, `.row-fluid span2` etc has been specifically selected in order to set their width in bootstrap in various places.  Therefor `[class*="span"]` is unable to override them because it is more general selector. And this is way we need `.row-fluid [class*="span"]` for selecting these elements.